# powershell outlook automation namespace

Tags: powershell, automation, outlook, activexobject

I'm working with automating the opening of a public folder by EntryID from IE with javascript and activex and ran across some errors. To debug I've re-wrote it as a power shell script.

```
$eid = "HEX EntryID FOR PUBLIC FOLDER";

$o = new-object -com outlook.application;
$ns = $o.GetNamespace("MAPI");
#$ns #if this line is commented, error
$f = $ns.GetFolderFromID($eid)
$f.Display();
```

If I shut outlook down completely, and then run the script I get the following error

```
Exception calling "GetFolderFromID" with "2" argument(s): "The messaging interface has   returned an unknown error. If the problem persists, restart Outlook."
At G:\scripts\outlook.ps1:5 char:25
+ $f = $ns.GetFolderFromID <<<< ($eid)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

If I uncomment the $ns line, everything works fine, even if its removed again. That is, until I close out of Outlook completely, almost as if the $ns com object isn't being truly initialized until I output it to the console.

I'd like to know:

- why calling `$ns` fixes the problem
- why powershell thinks I'm passing 2 arguments
- is there a way to implement this workaround
  in javascript

Answer (score 0):

The GetFolderFromID() requires two arguments: EntryID and StoreID of folder wanted.

This code gives no error and show outlook with PublicFolder selected:

```
$o = new-object -com outlook.application;
$ns = $o.GetNamespace("MAPI");
$cp = $ns.Folders # FolderClass ComObject containing all Outlook folders, usually first is the PublicFolder
$f = $ns.GetFolderFromID( $cp.GetFirst().EntryID ,$cp.GetFirst().StoreID )
$f.Display();
```

Using your code I can't do it, `$ns` line commented or not.

Comment: GetFolderFromID() requires only one argument. Second argument Store ID is optional. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219901(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: @Pete Ok, I have not read msdn just looked at OverloadDefinitions of the method. Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the public folders store programatically:

```
$ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$pf = $ol.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders | Where-Object {$_.FolderPath -like "\\Public Folders*"}
$pf.Display()
```

Comment: I'm specifically trying to open a folder that I have a specific EntryID for, not the base of the store. I've updated my question for clarity.